# Release the opencv Image in a stl container?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am having a problem of releasing the opencv image stored in a stl container. I am developing a system saving the last few frames from a camera. I need a container to store the images. But when I try to use the iterator get access to the image and release them, things go wrong.
like this.

```
deque<IplImage> ImageQue;
IplImage * temp=cvCreateImage(cvSize(30, 30), 8, 3);
ImageQue.push_back(*temp);
deque<IplImage>::iterator it=ImageQue.begin();
//temp and temp2 pointing different mem 
IplImage * temp2=&*it;
//this goes wrong. execption at memory location.
cvReleaseImage(&temp2);
```

If I try this.

```
IplImage * try1=cvCreateImage(cvSize(30, 30), 8, 3);
//try1 and try2 are pointing the same mem.
IplImage * try2=&*try1;
//things alright here.
cvReleaseImage(&try2);
```

I think the problem is here.
deque::iterator it=ImageQue.begin();
IplImage * temp2=&*it;

Any idea of this? or suggestion if I want to release the image in a stl container?

Comment: Do you really need an image in type of IplImage?
IplImage is a type used for OpenCV C interface, You can try the cv::Mat type instead of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're mixing and matching your pointer indirection a bit. It is probably a good idea not to do this:

```
deque<IplImage> ImageQue; 
IplImage * temp=cvCreateImage(cvSize(30, 30), 8, 3); 
ImageQue.push_back(*temp);
```

You should probably be using a container of pointers (and not use leading capitals for instance names):

```
deque<IplImage*> imageQueue; 
imageQueue.push_backcvCreateImage(cvSize(30, 30), 8, 3));
// ...
auto itr = imageQueue.begin();
IplImage* temp = *itr;
cvReleaseImage(&temp);
```

Sort of thing. More importantly, perhaps... if you're going to be destroying your images like that, you should probably take them out of the container first, as you probably don't want a queue of dangling pointers.

```
IplImage* temp  = imageQueue.front();
imageQueue.pop_front();
cvReleaseImage(&temp);
```

You could also consider using some kind of smart pointer (which automatically releases the IplImage at the end of its life)... don't recent versions of OpenCV include a nice C++ api for this sort of thing, or am I mistaken? A `std::shared_ptr` might also work, given a suitable custom deleter.

Comment: The "nice" C++ api includes `cv::Mat`, which essentially does a lot of what you would achieve with smart pointers.

Comment: thanks a lot, I just think of this and fix this problem. Thanks again for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think the C-interface's `IplImage` likes to be copied by value, as you are attempting to do. If you want to use C++ containers, which operate with value semantics, you should either use containers of `IplImage*`, or, even better, use the C++ interface's [cv::Mat](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat), which uses RAII to take care of copying and releasing resources (i.e. you do not have to worry about releasing).

Comment: @Rook `cv::Mat` replaces `IplImage` in OpenCV's the C++ interface. `IplImage` really shouldn't be used in C++, and using `Ptr<ImpImage>` would only complicate matters, because I cannot see any means to control the deletion action. `shared_ptr` could be OK, but one would have to specify the deletion action.

Comment: Yeah, I spotted that shortly after I replied, and deleted my comment. Sorry if I've left your response dangling without any context!

Comment: `Ptr<ImpImage>` would work, but you would need to supply a custom deleter. There's example code for automatically closing a file pointer just above the `Mat` documentation in your link. But it would be silly to use that if there was already a perfectly good purpose-built image container to use instead, eg `Mat`.

Comment: @Rook I hadn't realised `Ptr<T>` had custom deletion, because it is implemented in such a bizarre fashion (yikes!) Thanks for pointing it out though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the std::shared_ptr in C++11 or Boost equivalent in C++03.

You can store in the stl container the shared_ptr of your object, but you need to specify the deleter (the default one is operator delete).

You can assign the deleter of your pointer in the constructor of the shared_ptr. In your case cvReleaseImage function.

From [Boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#Synopsis):

> template shared_ptr(Y * p, D d); template shared_ptr(Y * p, D d, A a);
>
> ```
> Requirements: p must be convertible to T *. D must be CopyConstructible. 
>               The copy constructor and destructor of D must not
>               throw. The expression d(p) must be well-formed, must not invoke
>               undefined behavior, and must not throw exceptions. A must be an
>               allocator, as described in section 20.1.5 (Allocator requirements) of
>               the C++ Standard.
>
> Effects: Constructs a shared_ptr that owns the pointer p and the deleter d. 
>          The second constructor allocates memory using a copy of a.
>
> Postconditions: use_count() == 1 && get() == p.
>
> Throws: std::bad_alloc, or an implementation-defined 
>         exception when a resource other than memory could not be obtained.
>
> Exception safety: If an exception is thrown, d(p) is called.
>
> Notes: When the the time comes to delete the object pointed to by p, 
>        the stored copy of d is invoked with the stored copy of p as an
>        argument.
> ```
>
> [Custom deallocators allow a factory function returning a shared_ptr
>   to insulate the user from its memory allocation strategy. Since the
>   deallocator is not part of the type, changing the allocation strategy
>   does not break source or binary compatibility, and does not require a
>   client recompilation. For example, a "no-op" deallocator is useful
>   when returning a shared_ptr to a statically allocated object, and
>   other variations allow a shared_ptr to be used as a wrapper for
>   another smart pointer, easing interoperability.
>
> The support for custom deallocators does not impose significant
>   overhead. Other shared_ptr features still require a deallocator to be
>   kept.
>
> The requirement that the copy constructor of D does not throw comes
>   from the pass by value. If the copy constructor throws, the pointer is
>   leaked. Removing the requirement requires a pass by (const) reference.
>
> The main problem with pass by reference lies in its interaction with
>   rvalues. A const reference may still cause a copy, and will require a
>   const operator(). A non-const reference won't bind to an rvalue at
>   all. A good solution to this problem is the rvalue reference proposed
>   in N1377/N1385.]